# ASP Classic on IIS 7 - variable data seems to pass between sessions

Tags: sql, asp-classic, iis-7

I have a page that collects data that is passed to it via http querystring and parses it and stores it in SQL.  The data includes drive data about the server checking in. The check in occurs with a custom VB service.

What seems to happen intermittently, is drive data from one server seems to end up stored under another server.  Here's a meta representation of the mix-up:

SERVER--TIME--CDRIVE--DDRIVE--NOTE

SERVER-A--1215--355--126--This is a normal check-in for Server-A

SERVER-B--1215--1267--426--This is a normal check-in for Server-B

SERVER-A--1230--1267--426--This is a garbled check-in with B's data instead of A's

SERVER-B--1230--1267--426--This is normal, but is where the bad data comes from

The mix-up does not occur between any particular servers, just between two servers that happened to check in at the same moment.  I have tried disabling output caching and most recently I have tried adding "session.abandon" to my code.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I don't do web development as my primary task. I didn't even notice the issue until I set the drive data to loop after 7 days instead of looping every 24 hours.

Here's the code - the include just creates an "oconn" sql object.

```
<%language=vbscript%>
<!--#include file="includes/db.inc"-->  
<%  
'Variable Declaration  
'---------------------  
Private hsid  

'COMMON SECTION  
'--------------  
hsid = request.querystring("hsid")  
if isnumeric(hsid) then  
    hsid = cint(hsid)  
else  
    oconn.close  
    session.abandon  
    response.end  
end if  

sessionid = now() & hsid  
Session("SessionID") = sessionid  
response.write(Session("SessionID") & "<br/>")  

htime = now()  
hdate = datevalue(htime)  
hhour = hour(htime)  
hminute = minute(htime)  
hdur = 300  
hver = request.querystring("hver")  
if hver = "" then  
    hver = "Legacy"  
end if  
hupver = request.querystring("hupver")  
if hupver = "" then  
    hupver = "Legacy"  
end if  
response.write("hupver = *" & hupver & "*<br/>")  

'Stop processing if the server is not supported or the Company is not Icon.  
sql = "select u.txtUserFirstName from users u inner join site s on u.fkySiteID = s.keySiteID inner join Company c on s.fkyCompanyID = c.keyCompanyID where u.keyUserID = " & hsid & " and u.binUserSupport = 1 and c.binCompanyIcon = 1"
set rs = oconn.execute(sql)
if rs.eof then
    response.write("No Support")
    session.abandon
    response.end
end if
rs.close
set rs = nothing

function getfree(inputstring)
    gfindex = instr(inputstring,"-")
'   response.write(gfindex & "<br/>")
    outputstring = mid(inputstring, 1, gfindex-1)
    getfree = outputstring
end function

function getfull(inputstring)
    gfindex = instr(inputstring,"-")
    outputstring = mid(inputstring, gfindex+1, len(inputstring)-gfindex)
    getfull = outputstring
end function

'DRIVES SECTION
'--------------
drivelow = 0 'captures whether any drive is below 1 GB free space for later use
Private drivearr(3,26)
'drivearr(1,x) is for thresholds, (2,x) is for free space, (3,x) is for total capacity
'all drives will actually count from 3 (c) to 26 (z)

'we collect drive threshold settings from the DriveThreshold table, or otherwise generate a default entry for it.
sql = "select * from DriveThreshold where fkyUserID = " & hsid
set rs = oconn.execute(sql)
if not rs.eof then
    drivearr(1,3) = cdbl(rs("intcdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,4) = cdbl(rs("intddrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,5) = cdbl(rs("intedrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,6) = cdbl(rs("intfdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,7) = cdbl(rs("intgdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,8) = cdbl(rs("inthdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,9) = cdbl(rs("intidrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,10) = cdbl(rs("intjdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,11) = cdbl(rs("intkdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,12) = cdbl(rs("intldrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,13) = cdbl(rs("intmdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,14) = cdbl(rs("intndrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,15) = cdbl(rs("intodrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,16) = cdbl(rs("intpdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,17) = cdbl(rs("intqdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,18) = cdbl(rs("intrdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,19) = cdbl(rs("intsdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,20) = cdbl(rs("inttdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,21) = cdbl(rs("intudrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,22) = cdbl(rs("intvdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,23) = cdbl(rs("intwdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,24) = cdbl(rs("intxdrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,25) = cdbl(rs("intydrive"))*1024
    drivearr(1,26) = cdbl(rs("intzdrive"))*1024
else
    sql = "insert into DriveThreshold (fkyUserID, intCDrive, intDDrive, intEDrive, intFDrive, intGDrive, intHDrive, intIDrive, intJDrive, intKDrive, intLDrive, intMDrive, intNDrive, intODrive, intPDrive, intQDrive, intRDrive, intSDrive, intTDrive, intUDrive, intVDrive, intWDrive, intXDrive, intYDrive, intZDrive) values (" & hsid & ", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)"
    oconn.execute(sql)
    for i = 3 to 26
        drivearr(1,i) = 1*1024
    next
end if
rs.close
set rs = nothing

'Load the null value (-1) for all positions in the drivearr for free spacce (2,x) and total capacity (3,x)
for i = 3 to 26
    drivearr(2,i) = -1
    drivearr(3,i) = -1
next

cdrive = request.querystring("c") 'collect C Drive data
'   response.write("cdrive=" & cdrive & "<br/>")
    if len(cdrive) > 3 then
        drivearr(2,3) = getfree(cdrive)
        drivearr(3,3) = getfull(cdrive)
    end if

if drivearr(2,3) > -1 then     'only if C Drive is being monitored do we do the rest of the work
    ddrive = request.querystring("d")
'       response.write("ddrive=" & ddrive & "<br/>")
        if len(ddrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,4) = getfree(ddrive)
            drivearr(3,4) = getfull(ddrive)
        end if
    edrive = request.querystring("e")
'       response.write("edrive=" & edrive & "<br/>")
        if len(edrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,5) = getfree(edrive)
            drivearr(3,5) = getfull(edrive)
        end if
    fdrive = request.querystring("f")
        if len(fdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,6) = getfree(fdrive)
            drivearr(3,6) = getfull(fdrive)
        end if
    gdrive = request.querystring("g")
        if len(gdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,7) = getfree(gdrive)
            drivearr(3,7) = getfull(gdrive)
        end if
    hdrive = request.querystring("h")
        if len(hdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,8) = getfree(hdrive)
            drivearr(3,8) = getfull(hdrive)
        end if
    idrive = request.querystring("i")
        if len(idrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,9) = getfree(idrive)
            drivearr(3,9) = getfull(idrive)
        end if
    jdrive = request.querystring("j")
        if len(jdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,10) = getfree(jdrive)
            drivearr(3,10) = getfull(jdrive)
        end if
    kdrive = request.querystring("k")
        if len(kdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,11) = getfree(kdrive)
            drivearr(3,11) = getfull(kdrive)
        end if
    ldrive = request.querystring("l")
        if len(ldrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,12) = getfree(ldrive)
            drivearr(3,12) = getfull(ldrive)
        end if
    mdrive = request.querystring("m")
        if len(mdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,13) = getfree(mdrive)
            drivearr(3,13) = getfull(mdrive)
        end if
    ndrive = request.querystring("n")
        if len(ndrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,14) = getfree(ndrive)
            drivearr(3,14) = getfull(ndrive)
        end if
    odrive = request.querystring("o")
        if len(odrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,15) = getfree(odrive)
            drivearr(3,15) = getfull(odrive)
        end if
    pdrive = request.querystring("p")
        if len(pdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,16) = getfree(pdrive)
            drivearr(3,16) = getfull(pdrive)
        end if
    qdrive = request.querystring("q")
        if len(qdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,17) = getfree(qdrive)
            drivearr(3,17) = getfull(qdrive)
        end if
    rdrive = request.querystring("r")
        if len(rdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,18) = getfree(rdrive)
            drivearr(3,18) = getfull(rdrive)
        end if
    sdrive = request.querystring("s")
        if len(sdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,19) = getfree(sdrive)
            drivearr(3,19) = getfull(sdrive)
        end if
    tdrive = request.querystring("t")
        if len(tdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,20) = getfree(tdrive)
            drivearr(3,20) = getfull(tdrive)
        end if
    udrive = request.querystring("u")
        if len(udrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,21) = getfree(udrive)
            drivearr(3,21) = getfull(udrive)
        end if
    vdrive = request.querystring("v")
        if len(vdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,22) = getfree(vdrive)
            drivearr(3,22) = getfull(vdrive)
        end if
    wdrive = request.querystring("w")
        if len(wdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,23) = getfree(wdrive)
            drivearr(3,23) = getfull(wdrive)
        end if
    xdrive = request.querystring("x")
        if len(xdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,24) = getfree(xdrive)
            drivearr(3,24) = getfull(xdrive)
        end if
    ydrive = request.querystring("y")
        if len(ydrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,25) = getfree(ydrive)
            drivearr(3,25) = getfull(ydrive)
        end if
    zdrive = request.querystring("z")
        if len(zdrive) > 3 then
            drivearr(2,26) = getfree(zdrive)
            drivearr(3,26) = getfull(zdrive)
        end if

    'Test to see if any of the drives are low
    for i = 3 to 26
        if drivearr(2,i) > -1 then
            if cdbl(drivearr(2,i)) < cdbl(drivearr(1,i)) then drivelow = 1
        end if
    next

    if drivelow = 1 then  'we set the toggle for the server having 1+ drives low in the Users table.
        sql = "update Users set binServerDriveLow = 1 where keyUserID = " & hsid
        oconn.execute(sql)
    else
        sql = "update Users set binServerDriveLow = 0 where keyUserID = " & hsid
        oconn.execute(sql)
    end if

    '----This section determines which of 2016 5-minute-intervals the check-in time matches and rounds the check-in time
    rdate = hdate
    rdayofweek = weekday(hdate)
    rhour = hhour
    rsequence = round(hminute/5,0)
    if rsequence = 12 then
        rsequence = 0
        rhour = rhour + 1
        if rhour = 24 then
            rhour = 0
            rdate = dateadd("d", 1, rdate)
            rdayofweek = weekday(rdate)
        end if
    end if
    rminute = rsequence * 5
    rindex = ((rdayofweek-1) * 288) + (rhour * 12) + rsequence + 1
    rtime = rdate & " " & timeserial(rhour, rminute, 0)
    response.write("rindex: " & rindex & "<br />")

    '----Determines which key value matches the sequence number in the DailyDrive table for use in data punch-down.
    sql = "select keyDriveDailyID from DriveDaily where intDriveDailyIndex = " & rindex & " and fkyUserID = " & hsid
    set rs = oconn.execute(sql)
    if not rs.eof then 'if the sequence is found in the table and has a key value then update the table, otherwise....
        ddkey = rs("keyDriveDailyID")
        sql = "update DriveDaily set datDriveDailyTime = '" & rtime & "', CDrive = " & drivearr(2,3) & ", CDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,3) & ", DDrive = " & drivearr(2,4) & ", DDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,4) & ",  EDrive = " & drivearr(2,5) & ", EDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,5) & ",  FDrive = " & drivearr(2,6) & ", FDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,6) & ",  GDrive = " & drivearr(2,7) & ", GDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,7) & ",  HDrive = " & drivearr(2,8) & ", HDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,8) & ",  IDrive = " & drivearr(2,9) & ",  IDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,9) & ", JDrive = " & drivearr(2,10) & ", JDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,10) & ", KDrive = " & drivearr(2,11) & ",  KDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,11) & ", LDrive = " & drivearr(2,12) & ",  LDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,12) & ", MDrive = " & drivearr(2,13) & ",  MDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,13) & ", NDrive = " & drivearr(2,14) & ",  NDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,14) & ", ODrive = " & drivearr(2,15) & ",  ODriveCap = " & drivearr(3,15) & ", PDrive = " & drivearr(2,16) & ",  PDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,16) & ", QDrive = " & drivearr(2,17) & ",  QDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,17) & ", RDrive = " & drivearr(2,18) & ",  RDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,18) & ", SDrive = " & drivearr(2,19) & ",  SDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,19) & ", TDrive = " & drivearr(2,20) & ",  TDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,20) & ", UDrive = " & drivearr(2,21) & ",  UDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,21) & ", VDrive = " & drivearr(2,22) & ",  VDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,22) & ", WDrive = " & drivearr(2,23) & ",  WDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,23) & ", XDrive = " & drivearr(2,24) & ",  XDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,24) & ", YDrive = " & drivearr(2,25) & ",  YDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,25) & ", ZDrive = " & drivearr(2,26) & ",  ZDriveCap = " & drivearr(3,26) & " where keyDriveDailyID = " & ddkey
'       response.write(sql)
'       response.write("<br />")
'       response.end
        oconn.execute(sql)
    else '...otherwise add a new entry to the table.
        sql = "select numCounter from Counter where txtTableName = 'DriveDaily'"
        set cs = oconn.execute(sql)
        if not cs.eof then
            ddkey = cdbl(cs("numCounter"))
        end if
        cs.close
        set cs = nothing

        sql = "insert into DriveDaily(keyDriveDailyID, fkyUserID, datDriveDailyTime, intDriveDailyIndex, CDrive, CDriveCap, DDrive, DDriveCap, EDrive, EDriveCap, FDrive, FDriveCap, GDrive, GDriveCap, HDrive, HDriveCap, IDrive, IDriveCap, JDrive, JDriveCap, KDrive, KDriveCap, LDrive, LDriveCap, MDrive, MDriveCap, NDrive, NDriveCap, ODrive, ODriveCap, PDrive, PDriveCap, QDrive, QDriveCap, RDrive, RDriveCap, SDrive, SDriveCap, TDrive, TDriveCap, UDrive, UDriveCap, VDrive, VDriveCap, WDrive, WDriveCap, XDrive, XDriveCap, YDrive, YDriveCap, ZDrive, ZDriveCap) values (" & ddkey & ", " & hsid & ", '" & rtime & "', " & rindex & ", " & drivearr(2,3) & ", " & drivearr(3,3) & ", " & drivearr(2,4) & ", " & drivearr(3,4) & ", " & drivearr(2,5) & ", " & drivearr(3,5) & ", " & drivearr(2,6) & ", " & drivearr(3,6) & ", " & drivearr(2,7) & ", " & drivearr(3,7) & ", " & drivearr(2,8) & ", " & drivearr(3,8) & ", " & drivearr(2,9) & ", " & drivearr(3,9) & ", " & drivearr(2,10) & ", " & drivearr(3,10) & ", " & drivearr(2,11) & ", " & drivearr(3,11) & ", " & drivearr(2,12) & ", " & drivearr(3,12) & ", " & drivearr(2,13) & ", " & drivearr(3,13) & ", " & drivearr(2,14) & ", " & drivearr(3,14) & ", " & drivearr(2,15) & ", " & drivearr(3,15) & ", " & drivearr(2,16) & ", " & drivearr(3,16) & ", " & drivearr(2,17) & ", " & drivearr(3,17) & ", " & drivearr(2,18) & ", " & drivearr(3,18) & ", " & drivearr(2,19) & ", " & drivearr(3,19) & ", " & drivearr(2,20) & ", " & drivearr(3,20) & ", " & drivearr(2,21) & ", " & drivearr(3,21) & ", " & drivearr(2,22) & ", " & drivearr(3,22) & ", " & drivearr(2,23) & ", " & drivearr(3,23) & ", " & drivearr(2,24) & ", " & drivearr(3,24) & ", " & drivearr(2,25) & ", " & drivearr(3,25) & ", " & drivearr(2,26) & ", " & drivearr(3,26) & ")"
'       response.write(sql)
'       response.end
        oconn.execute(sql)
        sql = "update Counter set numCounter = " & ddkey+1 & " where txtTableName = 'DriveDaily'"
        oconn.execute(sql)
    end if
    rs.close
    set rs = nothing
end if

'HEARTBEAT SECTION-------------------------------------------------------------
'   DATETIME SUBSECTION
'   -------------------
dt = request.querystring("dt")
if dt = "" then
'   do nothing
else
    dtyear = mid(dt,1,4)
    dtmonth = mid(dt,5,2)
    dtday = mid(dt,7,2)
    dthour = mid(dt,9,2)
    dtminute = mid(dt,11,2)

    dtstring = dtmonth & "/" & dtday & "/" & dtyear & " " & dthour & ":" & dtminute
end if

sql = "select datHeartLast, intHeartNext from Users where keyUserID = " & hsid
set rs = oconn.execute(sql)
if not rs.eof then
    hlast = rs("datHeartLast")
    hnext = rs("intHeartNext")
end if
rs.close
set rs = nothing
response.write("<br />hlast = " & hlast & "<br />hnext = " & hnext)

if hnext > 0 then
    hgap = datediff("s",hlast,htime)
    if hnext + 60 < hgap then
        sql = "select numCounter from Counter where txtTableName = 'Heart'"
        set rs = oconn.execute(sql)
        if not rs.eof then
            heartid = cdbl(rs("numCounter"))
        end if
        rs.close
        set rs = nothing

        sql = "insert into Heart (keyHeartID, fkyServerID, datHeartDownStart, datHeartDownEnd) values (" & heartid & ", " & hsid & ", '" & hlast & "', '" & htime & "')"
        oconn.execute(sql)

        sql = "update Counter set numCounter = " & heartid + 1 & " where txtTableName = 'Heart'"
        oconn.execute(sql)
    end if
else
    sql = "update Users set datHeartFirst = '" & htime & "' where keyUserID = " & hsid
    oconn.execute(sql)
end if

sql = "update Users set datHeartLast = '" & htime & "', intHeartNext = " & hdur & ", datHeartDT = '" & dtstring & "', fkyHeartTicketID = null, binHeartEmailSent = 0, txtHeartVersion = '" & hver & "', txtHeartUpVersion = '" & hupver & "' where keyUserID = " & hsid
oconn.execute(sql)

oconn.close
set oconn = nothing
response.write(rindex & " " & htime & " " & rtime)
session.abandon
%>
```

Comment: it does sound like the problem is going to be in the parsing script. could we see that? session abandon may not do it. resetting the session variables at the end of the script may sort it out but it does sound like there is more of a fundamental problem with how the script persists server info.

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: Mmm, can't see anything wrong with the code. You actually don't use session variables to retrieve the hsid so really you don't need to use session at all. Try changing the variable declarations from Private to Dim. I dont think thats the problem but worth a test. What sort of database are you using? Have you checked all the urls that request this script to make sure the error isnt in them?

Comment: Each server we have checks in with its own particular URL. It passes the hsid and other querystring values in the URL. There is no way for a server to pass its own hsid and then somehow pass drive values for another server.  It appears to be random, like some sort of collision at the IIS level. It punches down to a SQL database. I put in the session code and the "Private" declarations as an experiment, but it didn't help one way or another. It almost seems like some sort of bug in IIS/ASP where it doesn't always keep the variable data "private" between two different loads of the asp page.

Comment: 99% of the time the check-ins occur without this data mixing, but when I graph the free drive space for a server's hard drive it causes sudden spikes in free space when data from a server with more free space sneaks into the data set.  So a drive that hovers around, say, 8 GB of free space will have a spike to 1200 GB of free space that blows up the scaling of the entire graph. I have also been trying to figure out a reliable way to massage the data in the graphing program to eliminate the spikes.

Comment: for the massaging you could get an average of the last X amount of drive capacities and compare that to the new report as a percentage of. Then have a range of allowable percentages. That would stop spikes. It would be nice to find out what the real problem is though.

Comment: I agree with your technique. My graph is done via ajax from a php page. I haven't had time to dig into it and work out how to manipulate the array data. But it certainly would be better to know WHY the check-in asp page is randomly passing variable data between instances.

Comment: If any IIS 7 Wizards are out there with ideas on how to get the sessions to actually be isolated (as I suspect they should be by default) then I'm all ears. Even if it's "there's a bug in IIS7".  I posted up here because I have tried everything I can find online. The idea seems to be that the separate webpage calls should never be passing data between them, and yet they occasionally do. It's very odd.

Comment: Or even a suggestion on how to get the asp page to write its activity to some kind of log or text file so that I can go back and SEE if the data was actually corrupted by crosstalk.  If the log showed all normal activity, I could change my focus to the (much less likely) possibility of SQL somehow being the issue.